# How can I debug DynamoDBMapper not loading

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

My async task hangs when I call mapper.load():

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new...
mapper.load(Book.class, "frankenstein");
```

Not seeing anything in the console...how can I debug this or make sure everything is set up properly?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the version of the SDK you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Accompanying the AWS Android SDK distribution is a file called Logging.html: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/Logging.html Open the file as a web page and follow the instructions to get request/response logging displayed in logcat.